# Simplicity of Noetherian $B$, $A \subseteq B\subseteq C$, where $A$ and $C$ are simple Noetherian domains

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra, noetherian

After receiving important comments, which show that my original question has already been asked and answered, I now change my question to the following non-commutative setting:

Let $A \subseteq B \subseteq C$ be three non-commutative left and right Noetherian domains over $\mathbb{C}$.

Assume that $A$ and $C$ are simple.

Recall that a simple (left) Noetherian domain $R$ has a (left) division ring of fractions, denote it by $D(R)$, so we have $D(A) \subseteq D(C)$.

$D(C)$ is a free $D(A)$-module ($D(A)$ is a division ring, hence we have analogous results to the results concerning vector spaces over fields); assume that $D(C)$ is of finite rank over $D(A)$.

> Should $B$ also be a simple ring?

**An example:** Let $f: A_1(\mathbb{C},x,y)\to A_1(\mathbb{C},x,y)$ be a $\mathbb{C}$-algebra endomorphism of the first Weyl algebra $A_1(\mathbb{C},x,y)$ over $\mathbb{C}$, namely, the $\mathbb{C}$-algebra generated by $x$ and $y$ such that $yx-xy=1$. Denote $p=f(x)$ and $q=f(y)$. 
The image of $A_1(\mathbb{C},x,y)$ under $f$ is $A_1(\mathbb{C},p,q)$.
Now take $A:=A_1(\mathbb{C},p,q)$ and $C:=A_1(\mathbb{C},x,y)$,
and take $B$ to be the (non-commutative) $\mathbb{C}$-algebra generated by $A$ and $x$. It is well known that the first Weyl algebra (in our case, $A$ and $C$) is simple left and right Noetherian domain, see [Theorem 2.19, Corollary 3.9.1 and Corollary 2.11.1](http://web.maths.unsw.edu.au/~danielch/thesis/dcock.pdf).
Then I am asking if $B$ is also simple. ($B$ is Noetherian since it is affine over $\mathbb{C}$. $B$ is a domain since $C$ is a domain).

**Remark:** Another version of my original question can be the following, which I know how to answer: Let $A \subseteq B \subseteq C$ be three non-commutative rings, with $A$ and $C$ division rings, and $C$ is left algebraic over $A$. Is $B$ also a division ring? The answer is YES: Take $b \in B \subseteq C$. $C$ is left algebraic over $A$, so in particular $b$ is left algebraic over $A$:
$a_mb^m+\cdots+a_1b+a_01=0$, for some $m \in \{1,2,3\ldots\}$ and $a_m,\ldots,a_1,a_0 \in A$. Now continue with similar arguments as in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1501160/suppose-k-f-is-an-algebraic-extension-of-fields-prove-that-if-r-is-a-ring-w?rq=1), and apply [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1077301/about-rings-with-a-right-multiplicative-identity-1-such-that-every-element-in).

See also [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/288475/is-x-in-a-1-left-algebraic-over-the-subalgebra-generated-by-p-and-q-q).

Comment: Are your rings commutative?

Comment: Yes. (I will add that).

Comment: In that case simple means simply being a field.

Comment: In that situation, C is an algebraic extension of A and your question is «is a subring of an algebraic extension of a field which contains that field a field?»

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1124083/subring-of-a-field-extension-is-a-subfield

Comment: Thank you for your comments! So I should take non-commutative domains.. and perhaps also assume that they are Goldie, or preferably Noetherian in order to get division rings of fractions (and than talk about rank of free modules etc.)

Comment: Please write a complete answer to this question.

Comment: :) I will try to, but not now (since it is 2 AM here..).